# If event $A$ and $B$ are independent, and $B$ and $C$ are independent and $C\subseteq A$ holds, are $A\setminus C$ and $B$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory

Question in the title, here repeated: *If event $A$ and $B$ are independent, and $B$ and $C$ are independent and $C\subseteq A$ holds, are $A\setminus C$ and $B$ independent?*

I would say, this cannot be answered. Independence of $A$ and $B$ means $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ or that $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint (as long as the probabilities are $>0$).

But while $A$ and $B$ might not be disjoint and $B$ and $C$ are not disjoint, either, it might still be that $A\setminus C$ cuts out exactly the part of $A$ that contains the intersection of $A$ and $B$. Then $A\setminus C$ and $B$ would not have an intersection. Therefore, they would not be independent.

Then again, the cut might not remove the intersection of $A$ and $B$.

So, it cannot be said. The description allows space for both dependence and independence.

Is this correct? If not, where is my thinking error?

Comment: "Independence of $A$ and $B$ means $P(A\cup B)=P(A)P(B)$ or that $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint."

This is not true. $A$ and $B$ can be disjoint and still be independent, so long as the probability of one of them is $0$.

Comment: @5xum Thanks, you are right. Added

Comment: Also, independence means $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, not $P(A\cup B)$...

Comment: @5xum thanks, also corrected. Have you also an answer to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $A\setminus C$ and $B$ are independent. We have $P((A\setminus C)\cap B)=P(A\cap B)-P(B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)-P(B)P(C)=P(B)[P(A)-P(C)]=P(B)P(A\setminus C).$

Comment: I would like to add that independence is a technical concept and sometimes does not agree with intuition. (You can have 3 events which are 2-by-2 independent but not independent). Independence has nothing to do with disjointness.

Comment: But if two events are independent and probabilities are positive, they have an intersection. Then, I would not agree with "nothing to do"

Comment: OK, I would say very 'liitle to do' instead of 'nothing to do'! Don't try to bring in disjointness is proving results on independence. You are unlikely to have any success.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I appreciate it